# rake db:migrate:up version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a model with refund with integer, string
And when i am trying to migrate this new table i am getting following error.

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20130806144409



rake aborted!
No migration with version number 20130806144409
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:677:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:230:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
```

my migration file name `20130806144409_create_refunds.rb`

and this is the content in it

```
class CreateRefunds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :refunds do |t|
      t.integer :job_id
      t.integer :customer_id
      t.integer :amount

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: what migrations are there already? can you post the contents of the folder?

Comment: Ya i tried it since i already having table it shows an error as relation already exist.

Comment: See my edit in question.

Comment: Its not possible that it should say migration with version no does not exist. double check your file is inside correct(db/migrate) directory.